# linux backslash for dos

Tags: linux, shell, ms-dos

In linux I can use newlines in commands using the backslash in order to improve readability in shell scripts etc:

```
ls -l \
   --reverse \
   --human-readable \
   --full-time
```

Is this possible in DOS?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you say "DOS" I assume you mean Windows CMD shell. You can use the caret as a line continuation character.

```
ECHO hello ^
     world
```